# Encrypt SOAP request body with Python

Tags: python, soap, python-requests, zeep

I am using Python Zeep library to send SOAP requests. My problem is that the first request returns a certificate, which the endpoint expects to be used to encrypt the body for all the other methods.

I have attempted to sign requests, as per Zeep documentation, but it seems to not be the same thing.

I am not sure whether I am using the correct setup to perform this type of soap requests. Is there a way to encrypt the body using Zeep, or any other python library? (any working solution is accepted)

Unfortunately I had to anonymize some information, but please don't hesitate to reqest details if they may prove useful to resolving the issue

```py
from zeep import Client as cl
from requests import Session
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin

history = HistoryPlugin()
session = Session()
session.verify = False  # the response is signed with a certificate that fails verification, as it is just a placeholder certificate used in the test environment

transport = Transport(session=session, timeout=10, operation_timeout=10)
client = cl(url, transport=transport, plugins=[history],)

headers = {...} # Here the headers contain some unique ids and time of the request

response = client.service.getCertificate(_soapheaders=headers) # this returns a object that has a certificate at .body.content

certPEM = response('body')('content') # this is the certificate I need to use to encrypt the body

factory = client.type_factory('ns0')
expectedData = factory.expectedData(expectedData1=base64.b64encode(str.encode(someData)), expectedData2=str.encode(someOtherData))

# the factory seems to work just fine and the soap data object seems to be parsed correctly.
client.service.secondRequest(_soapheaders=headers, expectedData=expectedData) # This fails, with a "certificate not valid" error, and, according to the endpoint documentation, it sees to be caused by the fact that the body is not encrypted with the certificate received above
```

example of encrypted SOAP body (as per documentation)

```xml
<soapenv:Body>
    <xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-F3FCAC3C34D9D25B87163351066951112" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content"
        xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey"
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-F3FCAC3C34D9D25B87163351066951111"/>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</soapenv:Body>
```